# How to detect if an array of objects contains a specific object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Say I have an array of objects `arr = []`.
Inside `arr` there are many objects, all of the same format, say.

```
arr = [
  {
    "a": "asdf",
    "b": {
      "a": 2,
      "b": 1,
      "c": 4
    },
    "c": {
      "a": 0,
      "b": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "a": "xswh",
    "b": {
      "a": 4,
      "b": null,
      "c": 8
    },
    "c": {
      "a": 6,
      "b": 5
    }
  }
]
```

If I have a variable that is an object of the same shape:

```
obj1 = {
    "a": "asdf",
    "b": {
      "a": 2,
      "b": 1,
      "c": 4
    },
    "c": {
      "a": 0,
      "b": 1
    }
  }
```

How can I quickly check to see if this object `obj1` is inside the array? (meaning, if inside the array there is an object with the exact same parameters and values.

I tried `arr.includes(obj1)` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: i same ordered, stringify and check that string.

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `findIndex` function and do something like:

```
arr.findIndex(item => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

Comment: Note it only works if order of properties is identical

Answer (score 0):

Solution using - [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs)

You can use `find` on the collection (array) to find match for particular object value using `isEqual` which will perform deep comparison for you (in this case properties of the object).

```
_.find(arr, (v) => { 
   return _.isEqual(v, obj1);
});
```

`find` - ['Find' documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#find)

`isEqual` - ['isEqual' documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual)